# Kernel package processing and update-initramfs issues after upgrade from 19.04 to 20.04

Tags: boot, package-management, dpkg, initramfs, firmware

I just upgraded my Ubuntu from 19.04 to 19.10 a few days ago and ever since then I have faced an issue with booting.

When I boot up, GRUB boots into the new kernel image (of 19.10) and I see the manufacturer's logo and the system just freezes there. Once 20.04 rolled out, I thought this could be solved by upgrading to 20.04 but that didn't work out. During the 'cleaning build area' phase of installation, I got an error related to Linux firmware and it said something along the lines of 'moving back to old version' and aborted the update.

Now when I boot up, the same thing happens as before but when I run `sudo apt install` to install something (say node js), it doesn't install and throws up errors. The screenshot of the errors:

[image]

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic (5.4.0-26.30) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-firmware; however:
  Package linux-firmware is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup err
or from a previous failure.
                           No apport report written because the error message i
ndicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                      dpkg: dependency problems
 prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 5.4.0.26.32); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for cups (2.3.1-9ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-46-generic
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-46-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic (5.4.0-26.30) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-26-generic

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area.....(bad exit status: 2)
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=5.4.0-26-generic -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build...........(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtlwifi-new: 0.6 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/make.log for more information.
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me with what I should do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207958/error-24-write-error-cannot-write-compressed-block)

Comment: Well, it has been a long time now and I reinstalled ubuntu back then so I'm not sure if it would have worked or not :)