# apt-get upgrade returns with errors

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, dpkg, firmware

I could not find a solution to my problem, so decided to ask. When I run sudo apt-get upgrade - I get errors concerning the linux-firmware and initramfs-tools

Could you help me please?

Here is what I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (1.187.1) ...
ln: failed to create hard link '/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic.dpkg-bak' => '/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic': Operation not permitted
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.2) ...
ln: failed to create hard link '/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic.dpkg-bak' => '/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic': Operation not permitted
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: what's the output of `uname -r`?  According to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207958/error-24-write-error-cannot-write-compressed-block), the error might happen if you are running an older/newer kernel version.  Please confirm that you run `sudo apt update` before any other apt commands - you should to have the latest list of software before trying to install, uninstall, upgrade any software.

Comment: @Nmath thank you very much for your suggestion it actually worked. I had to delete all the older versions of my kernels, free the space on /boot and then it worked. When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`. No errors anymore.
Thanks again! Great community this is!