# ztsd crashes when upgrading linux-headers-5.13.0-40 on 21.10

Tags: package-management, upgrade

I was running `sudo apt dist-upgrade` on my Ubuntu Server 21.10 machine in preparation for upgrading to the new 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish, but unfortunately I'm hitting an error installing the `linux-headers-5.13.0-40` package.

Even stranger, the error is different every time! Here are the error messages I've seen so far:

```
zstd: ../lib/compress/zstd_opt.c:651: ZSTD_insertBtAndGetAllMatches: Assertion `memcmp(match, ip, matchLength) == 0' failed.
Caught SIGABRT signal, printing stack:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(pthread_kill+0xf8) [0x7fb57eb10828]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(raise+0x16) [0x7fb57eabc476]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0xd7) [0x7fb57eaa27b7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x286db) [0x7fb57eaa26db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x39e26) [0x7fb57eab3e26]
zstd(+0x5c34e) [0x55b92341d34e]
zstd(+0x10d8b) [0x55b9233d1d8b]
zstd(+0x10e86) [0x55b9233d1e86]
zstd(+0x1281a) [0x55b9233d381a]
zstd(+0x6aeb9) [0x55b92342beb9]
zstd(+0xa539) [0x55b9233cb539]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x94947) [0x7fb57eb0e947]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x44) [0x7fb57eb9ea44]
Aborted (core dumped)
E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -19 -T0 134
```

```
zstd: ../lib/compress/zstd_opt.c:646: ZSTD_insertBtAndGetAllMatches: Assertion `curr > matchIndex' failed.
Caught SIGABRT signal, printing stack:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(pthread_kill+0xf8) [0x7fa3d02ac828]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(raise+0x16) [0x7fa3d0258476]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0xd7) [0x7fa3d023e7b7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x286db) [0x7fa3d023e6db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x39e26) [0x7fa3d024fe26]
zstd(+0x5c310) [0x55eab6030310]
zstd(+0x10d8b) [0x55eab5fe4d8b]
zstd(+0x10e86) [0x55eab5fe4e86]
zstd(+0x1281a) [0x55eab5fe681a]
zstd(+0x6aeb9) [0x55eab603eeb9]
zstd(+0xa539) [0x55eab5fde539]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x94947) [0x7fa3d02aa947]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x44) [0x7fa3d033aa44]
Aborted (core dumped)
E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -19 -T0 134
```

It flip flops randomly between these 2 errors. They both seem to be related to `zstd`, so I tried `sudo apt install --reinstall zstd`, but this does not appear to have helped.

If I can't install this package update, I can't upgrade to 22.04. System information:

- `uname -a`: `Linux SERVER_NAME 5.13.0-41-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 14 20:06:04 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- CPU: `AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor`
- RAM: 32GB DDR4
- OS: `Ubuntu 21.10`

Can anyone help here please?

Comment: try removing some old kernels from /boot, you might not have enough space there for mkinitramfs to finish, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328459/ubuntu-20-04-linux-firmware-install-error-mkinitramfs-failure

Comment: alternatively you can try this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2469034&p=14067672 , it seems to be a memory error

Comment: `/boot` was only 16% used of 976M, so it's unlikely that was the issue? I booted into recovery mode on the old kernel and then did `sudo apt autoremove`, and this appeared to fix it. To ensure it doesn't happen again, I've switch from `zstd` to `gzip` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` as suggested there. Thanks!