# Kernel 5.13.0-27 installation failed while installing -- what do I do next?

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I ran `sudo apt upgrade` and the output included the following. What should I do now? Has my previous kernel been overwritten? I am avoiding powering off my machine, since I am concerned it might not be bootable now.

```
Setting up linux-firmware (1.187.25) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-46-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-46-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Then some lines related to some other general packages, then:

```
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic (5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.13.0-27-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: New kernels usually do not oeverwrite old ones. Run `ls /boot` to verify.

Comment: @mchid, yes, it does. I used it and answered my own question already, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by following an [answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1386311/1367411).

> Seems like some problems with the older kernels. Let's work together step by step to fix this problem.
>
> First, purge all the older kernels which are no longer in use or are causing errors:

```
 dpkg -l | egrep "linux-(signed|modules|image|headers)" | grep -v $(uname -r | cut -d - -f 1) | awk {'print $2'} | xargs sudo apt purge -y
```

> Run the apt -f again:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Then I ran
`sudo apt upgrade` and everything went off without a hitch.